# Write text on top of background image

Tags: asp.net, image, html, overlay

I had a look at similar questions, but i'm still stuck.

I am writing a website in ASP using MSVWD10.
For 1 page only, I want to have an image which is 960x700px that will have text displayed on top of it. This text will change frequently.
I tried to set this in the CSS, but the image seems to be duplicating itself.

Here is the CSS.

```
#about 
{
    background: url(img/about.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #888888;
    width: 960px;
    min-height: 685px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto; 
}
```

Do i need to set a div on the content page?

Comment: welcome to Stackoverflow. You don't need to put " (ASP.NET)" in your title - just put it in the tags. Also, the tag you wanted was asp.net not asp. The latter could refer to "Classic ASP".

Comment: Thanks John, Will remember this in the future.

Comment: The background image doesn't duplicate for me, [here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/L7fDp/).  Is it possible you've got something else overriding the `background` definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should get you started:

**HTML**

```
<div id="outer"><div id="inner">Some text</div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#outer{background:#ff0022;Text-align:center;width:200px;min-height:200px;}
#inner{margin:auto;}
```

You can see this in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/rvn5M/

Comment: Why not just `<div id="outer">Some text</div>` ?

Comment: Agreed. I'm not sure what I was thinking :-) Maybe I just like superfluous divs.  I'm gonna update the answer now.

Comment: Haha! The more the merrier... :)  To be honest, the question sounds more like a problem with a repeating background despite `no-repeat` being set, rather than a general inability to get text to display on a background.

Comment: Thanks town, had a look at Alison's answer and they both work. thanks

Comment: @idly: Glad you got it working.  Sometimes it's just a weird quirk that you need to work through.